# debugging chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code:

```
...

  function init() {
      getdata();
  }

  var txt;
  function getdata() {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET',myurl, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) if (xhr.responseText) {
              txt = xhr.responseText;
          }
      }

      xhr.send();
      console.log(txt);
  }

...

<body onload="init();">

...
```

Why can't I get `txt` value? Please help.
forgot to mention - all of this happens in background page, i dont have any other pages at the moment. i tried console via extensions overview for background page, but that console doesnt output anything.. :((

Comment: Do you know [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)? Or the Chrome console?

Comment: Yes, but your code doesn't work, you are missing a code `{` somewhere.

Comment: console doesnt say about { . it outputs undefined for txt..

Comment: i also have this question: does myurl have to always have .html file extension in it?? My myurl doesnt have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XHR request is asynchronous, so when you log `txt` to console immediately after sending it, the request hasn't completed yet so `txt` is *`undefined`*.

Either set it be run synchronously by setting `async` to `false` in the `open` command, or just stick `console.log(txt)` in the function you have bound to the `onreadystatechange` event already.

Comment: It's not just bad indention, I believe it's because either something is missing in the posted code or it is malwritten. Without more info, we won't know.

Comment: i tried to stick console.log(txt) just after txt = xhr.responseText; but it didnt help.. :((

Comment: What's `if (xhr.readyState == 4) if (xhr.responseText)` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Acorn Thanks a lot!! I got rid of if (xhr.responseText), stuck  console.log(txt) just after txt = xhr.responseText; and finally i got what i wanted!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because `onload` is called after the script has been processed and `console.log` has been called. Also, `xdr` is `undefined`.

Comment: `console.log` wont have been called as it's in the `getdata()` function.. but I admit, the bad indentation does make it a little hard to tell.

Comment: I would imagine a properly written code segment may address this issue.